# CLI, encoding-aware FTP uploader

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp, encoding

I've got a crappy webhoster where I need the filenames in iso-8859-1, my FS uses utf-8. Filezilla can handle encodings, but I need something that I can use in a script. Is there a program out there that I can use to convert file names on upload that can be called from bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are ways to script FileZilla but I'm not too familiar with them.  Try that first.

If not, what I can suggest is using lftp instead.  With lftp you can do the following:

```
set file:charset iso8859-1
```

and from there, upload the file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nope, you can't script filezilla from the command line.

Comment: That should be `ftp:charset`.

Answer (score 0):

```
convmv --notest -r -t iso8859-1 ./upload-queue/
```

Alternatively, hack something up using `iconv`.

```
srcfile=...
dstfile=$(echo "$srcfile" | iconv -t iso8859-1)

some-upload-command "$srcfile" "ftpserver:$dstfile"
```